# Selecting all attributes except some via XPath

Tags: debugging, xpath, xmlnode, set-difference

I would like to select all attribute nodes other than `id` and `class` attributes. What am I doing wrong here?

```
/x:html/x:body/x:*/@*[(local-name() != 'id') and (local-name() != 'class')]
```

Comment: That looks like it should work - what result is it giving you? Is it matching too much or too little?

Comment: Maybe `/x:html/x:body//x:*/@*[(local-name() != 'id') and (local-name() != 'class')]`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `local-name()` method in a predicate to filter out both `id` and `class`. For example, run this on the stackoverflow page itself in the browser console:

```
$x("//@*[local-name() != 'id' and local-name() != 'class']")
```

and its inverse to confirm:

```
$x("//@*[local-name() = 'id' or local-name() = 'class']")
```

**References**

- [Things to Know and Avoid When Querying XML Documents with XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950786.aspx)
- [XML Namespaces and How They Affect XPath and XSLT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950779.aspx)
- [How XQuery extends XPath](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xqueryxpath/)

Comment: @JLRishe Not enough code was provided, so replacing the namespacing with the `$x()` console API at least isolates the problem away from the XPath query.